# Modify an element's class inside another element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

So my HTML snippet looks something like this:

```
<div class="accordion-heading ">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" target="_self" href="#item-name">
        <b class=""> Items ({{vm.selectedItems.length}})</b>
        <i class='fa fa-chevron-down'></i>
    </a>
</div
```

So when it is expanded the HTML changes to look something like :

```
<div class="accordion-heading ">
    <a class="accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" target="_self" href="#item-name">
        <b class=""> Items ({{vm.selectedItems.length}})</b>
        <i class='fa fa-chevron-up'></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

What I want is based on some condition if the `chevron-up` class is applied, I want to remove the same and apply `chevron-down` class.

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-chevron-up")[0];
element.classList.remove("fa-chevron-up").add("fa-chevron-down");
```

But this does not function properly.
Because once we remove the class it says `can not add class to undefined`.

How to achieve the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Element.classList.remove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) does not return the class list, so you can't do method chaining. You have to do it like this:

```js
var element = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-chevron-up")[0];
element.classList.remove("fa-chevron-up");
element.classList.add("fa-chevron-down");
```